# Nvidia is overriding the brightness setting of KDE power management

Tags: nvidia, kde, power-management, brightness

I would like to be able to use the battery KDE widget to control the brightness of my screen.

If I move this slider of the battery widget in my taskbar, it shows a little popup in the bottom middle of the screen, saying “10%” or “50%” but it does absolutely nothing.

The same thing happens in system settings-> power management. the brightness slider does not do anything apart from showing that popup.

Power management is not working either, after 5 minutes, it should set the brightness the 50%. but once again, just the popup shows but the brightness remains the same.

Now, If I go in NVIDIA X server Settings ->DFP-0 -> color correction, there is a slider that controls the brightness of my screen. This one is working. It seems like KDE brightness settings are overriden by those of NVIDIA X server settings.

I tried adding this last line here in this section of /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but it didn’t solve this problem.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 760"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Is there a way to stop this brightness parameter from being overidden by NVIDIA settings ?